# VB: reporting num days in a month for a random week interval

Tags: vb.net

For a week interval spanning from say 2016/11/29 to 2016/12/05, is there some pre-packaged functionality in VB.NET for returning the number of days in `month_1` of the interval (== 2) and in `month_2` of the interval (== 5)?  For a week falling entirely within a given month, the number of days in `month_1` of the interval would be 7 and in `month_2` of the interval would be 0.

Comment: I've done a little bit of reformatting of your question and I converted the dates to ISO format (`yyyy/MM/dd`) otherwise the dates can be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such help that I know of. The `DaysInMonth` method is helpful here.

```
Private Sub DaysInWeek(StartOfPeriod As Date, ByRef Month_1 As Integer, ByRef Month_2 As Integer)
    Month_1 = Date.DaysInMonth(StartOfPeriod.Year, StartOfPeriod.Month) - StartOfPeriod.Day + 1
    If Month_1 > 7 Then Month_1 = 7
    If Month_1 < 7 Then Month_2 = 7 - Month_1 Else Month_2 = 0
End Sub
```

You can call the function like this:

```
Dim w1, w2 As Integer
DaysInWeek(New Date(2016, 11, 29), w1, w2)
```

Comment: In the question, the week begins on a Tuesday.

Comment: @Blackwood Good point. As I wrote my answer I reinterpreted the question. I believe that the code will work correctly since it's not depended on a "traditional" week. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will get the job done, though I still need to test it.  I'm still curious to know if there is canned functionality for this sort of thing available?

```
If (current_date.AddDays(7).Month() = current_date.Month()) Then
    num_days_in_mon1 = 7
    num_days_in_mon2 = 0
Else
    num_days_in_mon2 = current_date.AddDays(7).Day()
    num_days_in_mon1 = 7 - num_days_in_mon2
End If
```

Comment: I think you have a typo. The next to last statement should be `num_days_in_mon1 = 7 - num_days_in_mon2`.

Comment: If this isn't the answer you want, you might want to delete it and edit your question to add this code to help describe what the question means.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo, Blackwood, I've corrected it for those that peruse this post.